# Swipe off delete in RecycleView not working

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

My implementation of swipe to remove from recyclelist is not working, the item is swiped, but it returns immediately after being swiped. This code is intended to create an speech-to-text grocery list to help elder people.

(I'm a newbie in Android dev, I apreciate all feedbacks, thanks!)

```
public class GroceryListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
RecyclerView   recyclerView;
RecycleAdapter recycleAdapter;
RelativeLayout relativeLayout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_grocery_list);

    relativeLayout = findViewById(R.id.relativeLayoutRL);
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rvList);

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    recycleAdapter = new RecycleAdapter(this, prepareTextForRecycleView());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(recycleAdapter);

    //FOR SWIPE REMOVE ON ELEMENT ON LIST
    ItemTouchHelper helper = new ItemTouchHelper(callback);
    helper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
}

//FOR SWIPE REMOVE ON ELEMENT ON LIST
ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback callback = new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT | ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {
    @Override
    public boolean onMove(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSwiped(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
        Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(relativeLayout, "Item removido", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
        snackbar.show();

        MainActivity.speechAsText.remove(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
        recycleAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
};

private String[] prepareTextForRecycleView(){
    String[] ret = new String[MainActivity.getSpeechAsText().size()/2];
    int               j   = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < MainActivity.getSpeechAsText().size(); i++){
        if (!(i % 2 == 0)){
            ret[j] = MainActivity.getSpeechAsText().get(i-1) + " - " + MainActivity.getSpeechAsText().get(i);
            j++;
        }
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Does your Snackbar appear? If yes, the swipe is registered correctly, so the problem probably lies in your implementation of the RecycleAdapter Class, you should add its code into the question aswell, and maybe even the relevant parts of your MainActivity where your list is initialized etc.

Comment: Solutioned guys, the problem was caused by a wrong array handling.